# Spring MVC - JSP request parameter

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring controller where in I am setting some property in below fashion

```
mav.addObject("somestuff", "<div>something I am setting in controller</div");
```

When I try to get value of  somestuff in JSP page as below

```
<div class="ABC">
 ${somestuff} <br clear="all" />
</div>
```

It returns 0 for some reason.

Any clues idea why this is happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ModelMap` like below:

```
ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
modelMap.put("somestuff", "some content");
```